# Sorting alphabet in terms of numbers

Tags: python

```
def make_gradebook():
    return []

def make_module_info(module, grade):
    module_info = (module,grade)
    return module_info

def get_module(module_info):
    return module_info[0]

def get_grade(module_info):
    return module_info[1]

def get_level(module_info):
    for i in module_info[0]:
        if str.isdigit(i):
            return i

def add_grade(gradebook, module_grade):
    gradebook.append(module_grade)
    return gradebook

def sort_by_module(gradebook):
    gradebook.sort(key=lambda gradeb: gradeb[0])
    return gradebook


def sort_by_level(gradebook):
    gradebook.sort(key=lambda gradeb: get_level(gradeb))
    return gradebook


def grade_to_numeric_marks(grade):
    for i in grade:
        if i[0] == 'A':
            if i[1] == '+':
                return 90
            elif i[1] == '-':
                return 80
            else:
                return 75
        elif i[0] == 'B':
            if i[1] == '+':
                return 70
            elif i[1] == '-':
                return 65
            else:
                return 60
        else:
            if i[1] == '+':
                return 55
            elif i[1] == '-':
                return 50
            else:
                return 46
    return grade.sort()



def sort_by_grade(gradebook):
    gradebook.sort(key=lambda gradeb: grade_to_numeric_marks(gradeb))
    return gradebook

### for testing ###
gb      = make_gradebook()
cs1010s = make_module_info('CS1010S', 'A+')
cs2020  = make_module_info('CS2020', 'A')
ma1101r = make_module_info('MA1101R', 'C')
ssa1207 = make_module_info('SSA1207', 'B+')
cs4247  = make_module_info('CS4247', 'A+')
ea5001  = make_module_info('EA5001', 'B')

add_grade(gb, cs1010s)
add_grade(gb, cs2020)
add_grade(gb, ma1101r)
add_grade(gb, ssa1207)
```

`sort_by_grade(gradebook):` return a new copy of the gradebook that is sorted by module grade from high to low. Make sure that 'A+' comes before 'A'
I used `grade_to_numeric_marks(grade):` as an helper function but I am still not able to get the output I want which is `[('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('CS2020', 'A'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('MA1101R', 'C')]` What's wrong ?

Comment: And what output __do__ you get?

Comment: [('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]

Comment: which is unsorted. The ouptut i want is [('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('CS2020', 'A'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('MA1101R', 'C')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you, instead of having multiple `if/elif/else` checks, define dictionaries grade->value and sign-value. Then, in the key function `grade_to_numeric_marks` just sum up base points per grade and points per sign (+/- or empty).

For example (you may need to tweak values per grade/sign a bit):

```
points = {'A': 80, 'B': 65}
signs = {'+': 10, '-': -5}

def grade_to_numeric_marks(item):
    grade = item[1]
    return points.get(grade[0], 50) + signs.get(grade[1:], 0)

def sort_by_grade(gradebook):
    return sorted(gradebook, key=lambda x: grade_to_numeric_marks(x), reverse=True)

grades = [('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]
print sort_by_grade(grades)
```

prints:

```
[('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('CS2020', 'A'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('MA1101R', 'C')]
```

Or, as @clutton mentioned in the comments, define just one dictionary with a mapping grade to points:

```
{'A+': 95, 'A': 90 ... }
```

Then, you can simplify the sorting:

```
points = {'A+': 95, 'A': 90, 'B+': 70, 'B': 65, 'C+': 55, 'C': 50}  # need to define all of the possible grades

grades = [('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]
print sorted(grades, key=lambda x: points.get(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: I was just going to add basically the same thing... {"A+": 95, "A":90}, seems easier to me than doing the +/- thing.

Comment: @clutton yeah, or probably, just `{'A': value1, 'A+': value2, ...}`, since there are not so may options, thanks.

Comment: Not sure but could probably pull the function call out as well... grade_to_nemeric_marks(x) just becomes a lookup in the dictionary.

Comment: @clutton yeah, just `sorted(grades, key=lambda x: points.get(x[1]), reverse=True)`, simple and readable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an OO rewrite:

```
class Module:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def level(self):
        for ch in self.name:
            if ch.isdigit():
                return int(ch)

class Grade:
    grade_marks = {
        "A+": 90,
        "A-": 80,
        "A":  75,
        "B+": 70,
        "B-": 65,
        "B":  60,
        "C+": 55,
        "C-": 50,
        "C":  46
    }

    def __init__(self, grade):
        self.grade = grade

    @property
    def mark(self):
        return Grade.grade_marks[self.grade]

class ModuleGrade:
    def __init__(self, module, grade):
        self.module = module if isinstance(module, Module) else Module(module)
        self.grade  = grade  if isinstance(grade,  Grade ) else Grade(grade)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.module.name, self.grade.grade)

class StudentGrades:
    sortkeys = {
        "module": lambda mg: mg.module.name,
        "level":  lambda mg: mg.module.level,
        "grade":  lambda mg: -mg.grade.mark    # Note: the -ve makes it descending order
    }

    def __init__(self, name, module_grades = None):
        self.name = name
        if module_grades is None:
            self.module_grades = []
        else:
            self.module_grades = [mg if isinstance(mg, ModuleGrade) else ModuleGrade(*mg) for mg in module_grades]

    def add_grade(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            mg = args[0]
            if isinstance(mg, ModuleGrade):
                self.module_grades.append(mg)
            else:
                self.module_grades.append(ModuleGrade(*mg))
        elif len(args) == 2:
            self.module_grades.append(ModuleGrade(*args))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Bad arguments to StudentGrades.add_grade")

    def sort(self, key, reverse=False):
        key = StudentGrades.sortkeys.get(key, key)
        self.module_grades.sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([self.name] + ["  {}".format(mg) for mg in self.module_grades])
```

And here's how you use it:

```
nf = StudentGrades("Norman Foster", [("CS1010S", "A+"), ("CS2020", "A")])
nf.add_grade("MA1101R", "C")
nf.add_grade("SSA1207", "B+")
nf.add_grade("CS4247", "A+")
nf.add_grade("EA5001", "B")

print(nf)    # original insertion order

nf.sort("module")
print(nf)    # alphabetical by module name

nf.sort("level", reverse=True)
print(nf)    # in descending order by level

nf.sort("grade")
print(nf)    # descending order by grade
```